# Which classes of font are generally the most readable at a glance?

Tags: fonts, readability, usability

When I say "classes of font", I'm referring to categories and styles such as geometric, gothic, grotesk, handwriting, humanist, etc. Out of all of these, which would be the most readable - by most people, at a modest size, with good/contrasting colours, at a glance - in most situations?

Comment: Is this for reading large amounts of text (like books)? Is it for reading signage on roads? What are the conditions? What culture of people are you talking about? What language? There are way too many variables at play here to get a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Serif body text font, like [Charter](https://practicaltypography.com/charter.html) or Georgia or Palatino, and humanist sans-serif like Verdana.

On print and modern displays, something like Charter or Georgia or Palatino would be best, a serif font that isn't too thin. Charter is [free download](https://practicaltypography.com/charter.html) and there's a freeware version of Palatino called TeX Gyre Pagella. Loads of options, though, like FF Meta Serif and Meta Sans if you're using Adobe Fonts.

On old screens, a big help is if the [font has been hinted](https://alistapart.com/column/font-hinting-and-the-future-of-responsive-typography/), meaning there are special pixel-by-pixel instructions for the computer for how to display it onscreen at small sizes. Georgia and Verdana have this. Open Sans or Source Sans are also very legible.

When legibility conditions are better an old-style book serif like Bembo Book is the standard, unbeaten for five hundred years. Arno or Garamond Premier too. On glossy paper you can choose something a bit crisper and lighter like a Didone.